# Authorize attribute restricts access before SetAuthCookie

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm having troubles trying to make work the  `Authorize` attribute in my ASP.NET MVC 4 project 
I'm trying to redirect to user to an authorized page whenever the login is correct.

This is the User Controller I'm using

```
Public Class UserController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    '
    ' GET: /Account

    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Return RedirectToAction("Login")
    End Function

    <HttpGet, AllowAnonymous>
    Function Login() As ActionResult
        If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
            Return RedirectToAction("x")
        End If
        Return View("Login")
    End Function

    <HttpPost, AllowAnonymous>
    Function Login(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As ActionResult
        Dim objService As New AuthenticateServiceClient
        If objService.ADAuthenticate(username, password) Then
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, False)
            Return RedirectToAction("x")
        Else
            ModelState.AddModelError("e", "The provided credentials are invalid")
            Return View("Login")
        End If
    End Function

    <HttpPost, Authorize>
    Function Logout() As ActionResult
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
        Return RedirectToAction("Login", "User")
    End Function

    <Authorize>
    Function x() As ActionResult
        Return View("Login")
    End Function

End Class
```

But when I'm having a correct login and the user is redirected I'm getting a HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized.

I'm missing some configuration?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite stupid error.

The published web.config wasn't the source control / local one. It was missing the config info.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/User/Login" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```